# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, dns

When I connect to the router and navigate on Chrome I get this error:

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET
```

I get the same even if I connect to another router in my area.
I tried the command `sudo -r dhclient [my interface name]` but nothing.

I even did [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1320070/comments/48) but the problem still remains.

Any help would be sincerely and gratefully appreciated.

```
$ ifconfig
enp0s26u1u2c4i2 Link    encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 16:99:e2:a1:b8:c8  
          inet addr:172.20.10.5  Bcast:172.20.10.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::989a:86a:dae6:a321/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:798 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1133 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:367120 (367.1 KB)  TX bytes:235907 (235.9 KB)

enp2s0f2  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 20:6a:8a:ee:3c:3a  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:4590 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4590 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:316485 (316.4 KB)  TX bytes:316485 (316.4 KB)

wlp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 74:e5:43:09:a7:55  
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a62d:2486:91a7:c953/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1379 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2583 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:171601 (171.6 KB)  TX bytes:304186 (304.1 KB)
```

```
$ ip route
default via 172.20.10.1 dev enp0s26u1u2c4i2  proto static  metric 100 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp3s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp3s0  scope link  metric 1000 
172.20.10.0/28 dev enp0s26u1u2c4i2  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.10.5  metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp3s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.102  metric 600
```

```
$ ping -c4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=166 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=186 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=103 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=182 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 103.263/159.795/186.746/33.473 ms
```

```
$ host google.com
google.com has address 216.58.205.78
google.com has IPv6 address 2a00:1450:4002:807::200e
google.com mail is handled by 50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
google.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Comment: How exactly do you "connect to the router"? What's the output of `ifconfig`, `ip route`, `ping -c4 8.8.8.8` and `host google.com`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I put what you asked in the op. I see the wifi connection among the available ones then simply connect to it. All the configuration for the connection are left automatic.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - Hello David, it seems to be an update error made by Google in chrome-stable and in chrome-beta both. Guess we have to wait a while until software bug is solved... But Firefox is working, true?!

Comment: No, not even Firefox :(

Comment: Can you establish any network connections at all? What's the output of `wget -O /dev/null google.com`?